# Puppet -- Applying puppet classes

Tags: puppet, hiera

I have a node 1 on which my application is going to be deployed using puppet. I have created a hiera file (node1_application.yaml) which states all the server details that this application is going to use such as

ldap_server = node2

mq_server   = node3

Is there any way that in node.pp , I only give node1 information which stats which class to be  applied on node 1. Then this class reads my hiera file and see that ldap server is on node 2 so ldap module should be applied on node 2.

It should be dynamically decided using my hiera file that which class should be applied on which node. Is it possible to do?

I am using puppet enterprise, hiera, facter, puppetdb and mcollective.

Answer (score 2):

I think is better to use `hiera_include('classes')`

If you have `node01.example.com.yaml` now you can write something like this:

```
---
classes:
  - base
  - ldap
```

Now in `node01.example.com.pp`:

```
node 'node01.example.com' {
      hiera_include('classes')
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible.

```
node default{
    if hiera("useldap") == 'true' {
      include ldap
    }
}
```

Will install `ldap` in every node that resolves `useldap = true`

Comment: This would mean in `node2_application.yaml` the hierdata key/value has to be set for `useldap` which as the op wants, doesn't dynamically decide which class to be applied on which node.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do it that way. You have to define within node2 that ldap class has to be included. It cannot be "deducted" by class/hiera in node1, since those are parsed independenly when applying changes to those particular nodes.

Answer (score 1):

I will recommended a newer solution, where nodes separate each role (if puppetmaster < 4.0).

Now, manifests/database.pp:

```
node /^(projectnameinthreechar)-([a-z]{3})-db([\d]+)\./ {
    class {
            "server::project::db":
                    ;
    }
}


class server::project::db ($paramteres) { ... }
```

Matching all node, who host names cathing this pattern:

```
 /^(projectnameinthreechar)-([a-z]{3})-db([\d]+)\./
```

Example:

```
web-can-db01
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can.

You should do the following.

**site.pp**:

```
node default{
  hiera_include('classes')
}
```

**hiera.yaml**:

```
---
:backends:
  - yaml

:yaml:
  :datadir: "/etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/{::environment}/hieradata"

:hierarchy:
  - "nodes/%{::trusted.certname}"
  - "common"
```

And then under hieradata you should have *nodes* directory which contains

**node01.domain.com.yaml**:

```
---
classes:
  - base
  - application
```

**node02.domain.com.yaml**:

```
---
classes:
  - base
  - ldap
```